# Get closest ancestor by partial class with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, closest

I need to get the closest ancestor by class, byt I need to use a partial class. For instance:

```
<div class="parent-1">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to do somenthing like that: `document.getElementsByClassName('child')[0].closest('.parent')`

This would return null, since the parent's class name is `parent-1`. But is there a way in which I could get the parent using just the partial class name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this

```js
const parent = document.querySelector(".child").closest("div[class^=parent]");
console.log(parent.className)
```

```html
<div class="parent-1">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```